# Problema com AJAX ambiente WEB

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Boa tarde.
Tenho um aplicação em localhost esta funcionando perfeitamente, mas na WEB não segue imagem:

Localhost[image: Localhost]

WEB
[image: WEB]

A lista de produtos neste caso é grande, e na web funciona quando seleciono somente até a metade da lista, nos últimos não funciona, passo esses dados por ajax e faço a validação por isset() para verificar se foi selecionado alguma linha, segue a função ajax:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#pedido').submit(function(){     //Ao submeter formulário
                confirma = confirm("Confirma geração do pedido?");
                if(confirma){   
                    $.ajax({            //Função AJAX
                        url:"gerarPedido.php",          //Arquivo php
                        type:"post",                //Método de envio
                        beforeSend: function(){ $("#btnSalvar").val('Aguarde...');},
                        data: $('#pedido').serialize(), //Dados
                            success: function (resposta){           //Sucesso no AJAX
                                $("#error").slideDown();
                                    if (resposta != false) {
                                         // Exibe o erro na div
                                        $("#error").html(resposta);
                                        $("#btnSalvar").val('Gerar Pedido');
                                    }else {
                                     // Exibe mensagem de sucesso
                                    // $("#error").html("<div class='col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 alert alert-success alert-dismissable'><i class='fa fa-check'></i>     <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'><i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i></button>O cadastro foi salvo com sucesso!</div>");
                                     $("#btnSalvar").val('Gerar Pedido');
                                    }

                            }

                    })                  
                    return false;   //Evita que a página seja atualizada
                }
                    return false;   //Evita que a página seja atualizada
            })
        })
 </script>
```

Somente no servidor WEB não esta funcionando.
Versão PHP Localhost: 5.3.1
Versão PHP Servidor WEB: 5.3.28

Código PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['selecao'])){
    foreach($_POST['selecao'] AS $key => $value){
        /*echo $value.'<br/>';*/
        $qtd = $_POST['qtd'][$value];
        $valor = $_POST['valor'][$value];
        $preco = str_replace(',', '.', $valor);
        $preco_bruto = $qtd * $valor;
        if(empty($qtd)){
            echo "Informe a quantidade para o produto ".$_POST['descricao'][$value]."";
            exit;
        }
        if(empty($preco) || ($preco == 0)){
            echo "Informe o valor do produto ".$_POST['descricao'][$value]."";
            exit;
        }

    }
```

}else{
    echo 'Selecione pelo menos um produto';
}

Comment: Aparece algum erro?

Comment: Ai que ta não da erro nenhum.

Comment: vc consegue receber o post? da um print_r nele e da um console.log no retorno do ajax.

Comment: não recebo o post, porque faço uma verificação com isset().

Comment: Coloca o código php

Comment: Já não sei mais o que fazer, são 137 itens na lista, qualquer linha que seleciona após a linha 111 não passa pelo ajax, e somente no servidor WEB em localhost não tem problema

Comment: Pode ser que o servidor esteja limitando o tamanho do post.

Comment: mas estou mandando como array, e qual seria a solução para isto?

Comment: notei que no servidor o post_max_size esta 64M e local 128M poderia ser isso?

Comment: Pode ser se o processamento utilizar mto memoria, por isso vc precisa verificar o erro no log ou habilitar eles.

Comment: e como faço para aumentar o post_max_size ja tentei por .htaccess e não  funcionou